# Login and Registration form in one view - Django

Tags: python, django

I'm stuck for good. I have a problem with having two forms (login in and registration one) in one view and html page. I've tried everything that i found but nothing seems to work for me. How do I write a statement that checks what is what and then proceeds to add user to database or log him in.
Thanks in advance

here is my "attempt" at this

```py
form = createUserForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get('submit') == 'sing_up':
            form=createUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
        elif request.POST.get('submit') == 'sing_in':
            pass
```

The html as you can see is messy because i'm stuck with the adding user to database

```html
<form class="loginForm" action="#" method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %} 
   {{ form.email  }}
   {{ form.password1  }}
   {{ form.password2  }}
   <button type="submit" class="btnLogin" name='register' value='sign_up'>Sing In</button>
</form>
<form class="loginForm" action="" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input class="inpLogin" type="text" placeholder="Login" name="log"/>
   <input class="inpLogin" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass" />
<button  class="btnLogin" type="submit"  name='submit' value='sign_in'>Log In </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML form you use together with the current state of this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  Using if condition {% if user.is_authenticated %} or you can try the one below

```
def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
        ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
```

Comment: How does this make a distinction between *registering* and *logging in*. This makes a distinction between *successful* and *unsuccesful* logins.

Answer (score 0):

is it as simple as the fact that you have "sing_up"/"sing_in" in the HTML, and "sign_up"/"sign_in" in the Python?